# Why if returns true after i change condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In html i have this:

```html
<div class="MyClass" id="1" onclick="functionX()">  </div>
<div class="MyClass" id="2" onclick="functionX()">  </div>
```

And my script:

```js
functionX() {
  if (document.getElementById("1").hasAttribute("onclick")) {
    window.onclick = e => {
      document.getElementById(e.target.id).appendChild(document.createElement("div", {
        class: "someClass"
      }));
    }
  }
}

if (document.getElementById("1").contains(document.getElementById("1").querySelector("[class='someClass']"))) 
{
  let foo = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
  for (let i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) 
  {
    foo[i].removeAttribute("onclick");
  }
}
```

When i click on the div which no longer has an attribute "onclick" the condition from the functionX continues to execute.

Comment: Once you add the `window.onclick` handler, it stays until you remove it.

Comment: Unrelated, but I don't think `id` should start with a number?

Comment: @NickSlash that used to be the case, but in HTML5 almost anything goes except spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you're removing an attribute.
Removing the attribute does nothing to remove the event handler.
You need to detach the handler.

Answer (score 0):

The if is not part of the function.

```
functionX() {
  if (document.getElementById("1").hasAttribute("onclick")) {
    window.onclick = e => {
      document.getElementById(e.target.id).appendChild(document.createElement("div", {
        class: "someClass"
      }));
    }
  }
}  // end of function


// not in fuction    
if (document.getElementById("1").contains(document.getElementById("1").querySelector("[class='someClass']"))) {
  let foo = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
  for (let i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    foo[i].removeAttribute("onclick");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know that this is not in function, but i want that to be not part of a function.